# Cannot use text, ntext, or image in a trigger

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL server 2008 R2, I'm getting the error:

> Msg 311, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ad_user, Line 28
>   Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables.

The purpose of the trigger is to update a user-group table when a new user is inserted. I've only included the SQL up to where the error occurs.). What confuses me is if I remove one of the integer declarations, I don't get the same error (just errors about not having declared the variable).

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[ad_user] on [dbo].[tps_user] 
FOR INSERT
AS

DECLARE @UserGuid uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @EndUserTypeGuid uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @UserTypeGuid uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @saGuid uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @GroupGuid uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @NewUser VarChar(250)
DECLARE @deptnum VarChar(250)
DECLARE @locnum VarChar(250)
DECLARE @CN VarChar(250)
DECLARE @NewOU VarChar(250)
DECLARE @pos1 integer
DECLARE @pos2 integer

BEGIN
SELECT @EndUserTypeGuid=tps_guid FROM tps_user_type WHERE tps_name='EndUser'
SELECT @saGuid = tps_guid FROM tps_user WHERE tps_title = 'SA'

SELECT  @UserGuid=tps_guid, 
        @UserTypeGuid=tps_user_type_guid,
        @NewUser=tps_title,
        @deptnum=usr_departmentnumber,
        @locnum=usr_locationnumber,
        @CN=usr_ou
FROM inserted   

    IF @UserTypeGuid=@EndUserTypeGuid
BEGIN       
  SELECT @GroupGuid=tps_guid FROM tps_group WHERE usr_departmentnumber=@deptnum     
    IF @GroupGuid IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      IF @UserGuid NOT IN (SELECT tps_user_id 
             FROM tps_user_group WHERE tps_group_id = @GroupGuid) 
      BEGIN
    -- Remove the user from other groups
    DELETE FROM tps_user_group WHERE tps_user_id = @UserGuid;                       
    -- Create Customer Group Membership from department
        INSERT INTO tps_user_group(tps_user_id, tps_group_id, tps_creation_user_guid, 
              tps_last_update_user_guid, tps_creation_date, tps_last_update)
    VALUES(@UserGuid, @GroupGuid, @saGuid, @saGuid, GetDate(), GetDate());
          END
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: Do you know how badly your trigger will break for a multi-row insert? e.g. `INSERT dbo.tps_user SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2` Also, what exactly are you going to do with all these variables? Finally, do any of these tables have a TEXT/NTEXT/IMAGE column? Why? These types are deprecated. Stop using them.

Comment: I don't have control over the column types in the database. All the variables are needed to calculate, from department or loaction or OU what location the inserted person works at so I can get the appropriate location guid and insert into the user-location table. Will it break if ANY column in the user table in ntext?

Comment: No, you should be able to use a trigger even if there is a text/ntext/image column you're not referencing. Are you sure `usr_ou` and the other columns you're referencing are not text/ntext?

Comment: One of them IS text, I think I get get away with eliminating it from the trigger, but if I can't, can I do some sort of conversion in creating the trigger to compensate for it?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and this error message will come at compile time, not at runtime, when you *explicitly reference* such a column in the `inserted` / `deleted` pseudo-tables. Unfortunately I think you will have to correct these columns in the underlying table in order to use them, since you can't just apply conversions against the columns in `inserted`.

What is blocking the client from upgrading these columns to use proper, first-class data types that haven't been [deprecated since SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for many good reasons (including this one)?

You'll need to re-write your trigger anyway. It currently is not multi-row safe. The trigger won't break once you have the data type corrected, it will just pick an arbitrary row from `inserted` and ignore the rest. So it needs to treat `inserted` as a set, not as a single row, since triggers in SQL Server fire per statement, not per row.

Comment: Seems the TEXT fields were added by a contractor, I ran a quick update changing the type to VarChar(250), or I can just not use that particular field as we have changed our AD structure. Could you please point me to how I can write the trigger correctly so it handles multiple rows? I'm a php programmer, this SQL became mine by accident...

Comment: @user973828 I think you're going to have to help me with the delete logic a bit. Only delete rows in the tps_user_group table where the group is the same department as the new user and the new user isn't in that group? If the user has just been added, how could they already be in a group?

Comment: Ah, because this was originally meant to trigger on insert OR update.

Comment: Ok, well I think once you have the trigger corrected, you should post the multi-row issue as a separate question. When the logic in the trigger makes sense, I or someone else will take a crack at re-writing it to properly deal with sets. Currently I can't make any sense of it.